# PayPal - Name of the product in billing information

Tags: paypal, billing

I've looked over the net but i couldn't find an answer.
Is it possible to make the product name that i offer to buy with Paypal to be visible on the billing of the credit card the customer gets?

I will make it more clear, lets say i have a product named "My Product" and the shop is "My Shop" so the client get at the end of the month the billing information from the credit card company and he will see there "My Shop - My Product".

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing which product you are specifically using it hard to say.  I would need more details, but if the service you are using through PayPal supports soft descriptors or level II/III data being passed over in the API request that you would be able to do this.

If you are using PayPal's Website Payments Pro, you can find information on SOFTDESCRIPTOR throughout the [Developers Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_nvpapi_developerguide.pdf).  The first reference in on page 28.

If you are using Payflow, you would want to also look at softdescriptors and Level II and III data in the [Payflow Developers Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf).  This will also depend on if your processor supports it.

Comment: is there an option with the Website payments standard integration ?
i checked the integration guide but couldn't find an answer